# Adding Bootstrap Tooltip to a <span> inside a <div>?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a span inside a div and I'm trying to add a Bootstrap 3 tooltip to it:

```
<div style="display:inline-block;margin-right:10px;">
  <h3>
    <span class="label label-default">
      Chickens: <span style="color:#fff;">3</span>
    </span>
  </h3>
</div>
```

How do I get this to work?

Comment: What part of this do you want to be in the tooltip?

Comment: The whole inline block :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are asking for something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/g74Ep/471/

```
<div style="display:inline-block;margin-right:10px;margin-top: 40px;">
  <h3>
    <span class="label label-default" href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="3">
      Chickens: 
    </span>
  </h3>
</div>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip(); 
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this: https://jsfiddle.net/s294csdn/

```
<div data-toggle="tooltip" title="This is a tooltip" style="display:inline-block;margin-right:10px;">
  <h3>
    <span class="label label-default">
      Chickens: <span style="color:#fff;">3</span>
    </span>
  </h3>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip(); 
    });
</script>
```